# Scala - Recursive method is return different values

Tags: scala, recursion

I have implemented a calculation to obtain the node score of each nodes.

The formula to obtain the value is:

- The children list can not be empty or a flag must be true;

The iterative way works pretty well:

```
class TreeManager {

def scoreNo(nodes:List[Node]): List[(String, Double)] = {
  nodes.headOption.map(node => {
    val ranking = node.key.toString -> scoreNode(Some(node)) :: scoreNo(nodes.tail)
    ranking ::: scoreNo(node.children)
  }).getOrElse(Nil)
}

def scoreNode(node:Option[Node], score:Double = 0, depth:Int = 0):Double = {
  node.map(n => {
    var nodeScore = score
    for(child <- n.children){
      if(!child.children.isEmpty || child.hasInvitedSomeone == Some(true)){
        nodeScore = scoreNode(Some(child), (nodeScore + scala.math.pow(0.5, depth)), depth+1)
      }
    }
    nodeScore
  }).getOrElse(score)
}
}
```

But after i've refactored this piece of code to use recursion, the results are totally wrong:

```
class TreeManager {

def scoreRecursive(nodes:List[Node]): List[(Int, Double)] = {

  def scoreRec(nodes:List[Node], score:Double = 0, depth:Int = 0): Double = nodes match {
    case Nil => score
    case n =>
      if(!n.head.children.isEmpty || n.head.hasInvitedSomeone == Some(true)){
        score + scoreRec(n.tail, score + scala.math.pow(0.5, depth), depth + 1)
      } else {
        score
      }
  }
  nodes.headOption.map(node => {
    val ranking = node.key -> scoreRec(node.children) :: scoreRecursive(nodes.tail)
    ranking ::: scoreRecursive(node.children)
  }).getOrElse(Nil).sortWith(_._2 > _._2)

}
}
```

The Node is an object of a tree and it's represented by the following class:

```
case class Node(key:Int,
                children:List[Node] = Nil,
                hasInvitedSomeone:Option[Boolean] = Some(false))
```

And here is the part that i'm running to check results:

```
object Main {
  def main(bla:Array[String]) = {

    val xx = new TreeManager

    val values = List(
      Node(10, List(Node(11, List(Node(13))),
        Node(12,
          List(
            Node(14, List(
              Node(15, List(Node(18))), Node(17, hasInvitedSomeone = Some(true)),
                Node(16, List(Node(19, List(Node(20)))), 
                  hasInvitedSomeone = Some(true))),
              hasInvitedSomeone = Some(true))),
          hasInvitedSomeone = Some(true))),
      hasInvitedSomeone = Some(true)))


    val resIterative = xx.scoreNo(values)
    //val resRecursive = xx.scoreRec(values)

    println("a")
  }
}
```

The iterative way is working because i've checked it but i didn't get why recursive return wrong values.

Any idea?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive version never recurses on children of the nodes, just on the tail. Whereas the iterative version correctly both recurse on the children and iterate on the tail.

You'll notice your "iterative" version is also recursive btw.

Comment: But how can i fix it? I've changed the recursive version to use n.head.children instead n.tail but still not working.

Comment: Should probably be `score + scoreRec(n.tail, score + scala.math.pow(0.5, depth), depth) +  scoreRec(n.children, score + scala.math.pow(0.5, depth+1), depth+1)` I think ?

Comment: No, already tried that. The correct value is 3.375 and if i do that way it returns 26.8125.